# Predict part of the input for a fixed target

Tags: regression

I dispose of a data set composed of 6 features all of them are numeric and a binary target(taking 0 and 1). How should I proceed in order to predict the values of 2 features knowing the target and the remaining fixed 4 features.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the scale of your dataset, but I guess what you're looking for conceptually is [Multi-task learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-task_learning). You can use this concept to carry out multiple tasks, or in your case regression predictions using a single model.What you can try doing is use the four features, and the target variable as input features to predict the two variables.

If you have a large dataset, you can look into deep learning multi-taking approaches [here](https://ruder.io/multi-task/). If you are familiar with python and [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/), you can try some basic multi task regression algorithms available as a starting point. This [algorithm](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html) might be helpful, its easy to use. If you are looking for a more deep learning approach, there are many architectures available online that you can try as starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Target and features are relative to their usages in the Model.

You may treat 4 Features, 1 target as 5 features and 2 unknowns as target

Then predict one of the two targets using the 5 features

Then use that target as one more feature to predict the other target using 6 features

You may start with [SGDRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html)